# SpatialPointsDataFrame too slow running FOR loop

Tags: r, gis, r-sp

I've run into a small problem where my `for` loop has been running for 3.5 hrs+. I have a Geodataset in `SQL Server` with a field called `Shape` that stores co-ordinates in `geometry` data type. Firstly, I connect R to my DB via `ODBC`  and retrieve the information I want (also converting the `Shape` column to something readable)

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(RODBC)
ch<-odbcConnect("SpatialAnalysis", rows_at_time=1)
df<-sqlQuery(ch, "select OBJECTID, LOT_NO, Shape.STAsText() as WKT FROM SRC_PLI_QLD")
cnt<-sqlQuery(ch, "select count(OBJECTID) from SRC_PLI_QLD")
```

This has 2.5 million points. I now read them into a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, reading the first element first.

```
point.sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(readWKT(df$WKT[1]),
                                   data=data.frame(OBJECTID=df$OBJECTID[1], LOT_NO=df$LOT_NO[1]))
```

Now I read the rest of the elements. **AND this is where the problem is**. It has been 3.5 hrs and still running.

```
for (n in 2:as.integer(cnt)) {
  point.sp <- rbind(point.sp, 
                    SpatialPointsDataFrame(readWKT(df$WKT[n]), 
                                           data.frame(OBJECTID=df$OBJECTID[n], LOT_NO=df$LOT_NO[n])))
}
```

What is the problem in the above mentioned `for` loop? Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: You are growing an object. BIG no no. Can't you do this in a single step?

Comment: Why are you reading one point at a time, i.e., using a for loop???? Won't this work?: `points.sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(readWKT(df$WKT), data.frame(OBJECTID=df$OBJECTID, LOT_NO=df$LOT_NO)))`

Comment: No I cant do this , because SpatialPointsDataFrame can only read one at a time.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in another way and it took less than 10 seconds. The change was in the query. Instead of retrieving `Shape.STAsText()` as a WKT object from `Shape` column, I retrieved the `Lat` and `Long` value from `Shape`

```
df<-sqlQuery(ch, "select OBJECTID, LOT_NO, Shape.STY as Lat, Shape.STX as Lon FROM SRC_PLI_QLD")
cnt<-sqlQuery(ch, "select count(OBJECTID) from SRC_PLI_QLD")
```

Then I did :

```
coordinates(df) =~Lat+Lon
```

and my dataframe df has been converted to a SpatialPointsDataFrame

```
> class(df)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```